# Fastapi python is not reading the request parameters

Tags: python, fastapi

So i'm using this code to clone a database,
the error generated when the request reaches the server is cannot concatenate type str with Nonetype
which means it's not reading the db_name parameter,
this code actually runs fine on my machine but when it in the server it generates the error described above,
the server log shows that the request reaches the server with exact needed path like "clone/test" for example but this still doesn't work even tho the parameter is passed
this is the server response:

```
"POST /clone/malek HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
```

this is the used code:

```
@app.post("/clone/{db_name}")
def clone_db(db_name):
    db_crea = 'echo CREATE DATABASE '+db_name + ' | mysql -u'+os.environ.get('db_username')+ ' -p'+os.environ.get('db_password')
    db_clone = 'mysqldump -u'+os.environ.get('db_username')+' -p'+os.environ.get('db_password')+' sw_erp --no-data | mysql -u'+os.environ.get('db_username')+' -p'+os.environ.get('db_password') +' '+db_name
    run(db_crea, shell=True) 
    run(db_clone, shell=True)
    return("database cloned", 200)
```

this is the displayed error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

i would apreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: It could mean that _any_ of your `os.environ.get` calls are `None` as well, which seems more probable. You can attach a debugger on that line and see whether `db_name` has a value, which I'd guess it does.

Comment: thank you very much for the response but the os.environ variables are working just fine,
db_name isn't an envirement variable actually it's a parameter that should be read from the incoming request to clone a database with that new incoming name so the problem have nothing to do woth the envirement vars

Comment: Attach a debugger, set a breakpoint on the line that errors out and look at the values; it should be possible to see which of your variables are `None`. Python 3.11 will also have better error messages for cases like this, but it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Could you post the full error message including any traceback that is shown?